# Solr: Incorrect numFound value

Tags: solr

I have try to add MySQL database to solr index. After finishing dataimport process, it show "1428760" documents are updated. But solr full search query show  `numFound="546195"`.

What is the problem? Why this mismatch?

Comment: are your records unique ??? as per the primary id ??? Solr will overwrite the records with same id.

Comment: Who shows 1428760 updated documents? Did you commit after finishing updating?

Comment: Thank you jayendra. Your point is correct. Now i set unique key for all records. Problem is solved.. Thank you guys....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check here:

http://lucene.472066.n3.nabble.com/Changing-value-of-start-parameter-affects-numFound-td2460645.html

Some guy says something about duplicate documents in solr. Looks like you should explicitly remove the document before reindexing it.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing the 1,428,760 comes from somewhere authoritative like the admin panel or CoreAdmin API, and the 546,195 is the number of matches against a wildcard search.

Check your headers. Is there a `partialResults` flag set to true? If so, then Solr hit its internal `timeAllowed` timeout when scanning through the index, and has only returned a partial set of all the matching documents.

This is one feature which demonstrate's Solr's preference for performance. It attempts to give you the most relevant results to your queries as quickly as possible. When a lot of documents match a query, it assumes that it can save some time and return quickly without impacting relevancy too much. Because who's going to paginate through half a million hits?

Anyway, without more details, this is just a guess and a brief explanation of `partialResults`.